# How to add a new Position Status for Position Data in PeopleSoft

Tags: peoplesoft

Hi PeopleSoft Gurus: I need help adding another position status indicator in Position Management.  Does anyone know how to add to the drop-down as noted here: https://monosnap.com/file/eRIbbVq4Wvqwn7acb7w8qsTYk07CpH# .

Right now, the options are:

```
Approved
Frozen
Proposed
Another One <--- Currently not listed, would like to add another
```

I'm thinking it's managed in the translation tables but I can't find it there. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is to add a new translate value to the POSN_STATUS field.

You can do this under the following navigation: Main Menu > PeopleTools > Utilities > Administration > Translate Values and search there for the field POSN_STATUS.

See screenshot:[image]

Comment: That did it!  Thanks Robin